# Copy SQL Library

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an ETL (Microsoft SQL Server 2014) that makes a copy of a large SQL Server database every month using a standardized naming convention for my organization.

Unfortunately, the name changes monthly so if I write code or make dashboards against the SQL Server database, I have to change the name of several products that make queries.

I would like to know if it is possible to make a SQL Server database that points to another database so I can have a name every month that doesn't change and won't cost me memory on the server.

For example I have the following database copies right now:

```
Jan_2018
Feb_2018
Mar_2018
Apr_2018
etc.
```

I would like to make a copy/version named `curr_month` and any queries to it point to the latest month available.

Comment: Why are you creating multiple databases? Why not put the data all in one database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps for this you can use [synonyms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

> A synonym is a database object that serves the following purposes:
>
> - Provides an alternative name for another database object, referred to
>     as the base object, that can exist on a local or remote server.
> - Provides a layer of abstraction **that protects a client application
>     from changes made to the name or location of the base object**.

The idea behind of this that an empty database to be created which will contain synonyms for every user object of your custom database [Apr_2018].

Therefore, when [May_2018] delivered synonyms need to be recreated to point to this new db.

Of course, (re) creation of synonyms is to be automated

Synonyms will not consume memory, also in contrast with views they will not break if schema of underlying object was modified

Answer (score 0):

As Alexander has said synonyms is your best bet.  In the interest of knowing HOW to automate such a thing see below.  You can go ahead and run this to get the output of the statements it'll run, just uncomment all the `exec sp_executesql @sql` when you want it to actually do anything.

```
use [curr_month]
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- You could automate this even by creating a select off master.sys.databases
declare @database varchar(100) = 'AdventureWorks'

declare @table varchar(100)
declare @obj varchar(100)
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)

create table #names
(
    ident int identity(1,1),
    objname varchar(100)
)

declare @table_count int
declare @counter int

--------------------------------------
-- Get tables
--------------------------------------
truncate table #names

set @sql = 'select [name] from ' + @database + '.sys.tables where is_ms_shipped = 0 order by [name]'

INSERT INTO #names (objname)
exec sp_executesql @sql

set @table_count = (select coalesce(count(*),0) from #names)
set @counter = 1

WHILE (@table_count > 0 ANd @counter <= @table_count)
BEGIN
    select @obj = objname
    from #names
    where ident = @counter

    set @sql = 'CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[' + @obj + '] FOR [' + @database + '].[dbo].[' + @obj + ']';
    print @sql

    --exec sp_executesql @sql

    set @counter += 1
END

--------------------------------------
-- Get procedures
--------------------------------------
truncate table #names

set @sql = 'select [name] from ' + @database + '.sys.procedures where is_ms_shipped = 0 order by [name]'

INSERT INTO #names (objname)
exec sp_executesql @sql

set @table_count = (select coalesce(count(*),0) from #names)
set @counter = 1

WHILE (@table_count > 0 ANd @counter <= @table_count)
BEGIN
    select @obj = objname
    from #names
    where ident = @counter

    set @sql = 'CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[' + @obj + '] FOR [' + @database + '].[dbo].[' + @obj + ']';
    print @sql

    --exec sp_executesql @sql

    set @counter += 1
END

-- etc. if you have views, functions, etc...

drop table #names
```

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, my reaction would be "store it all in one database and fix the table structures".  However, this seems to be some sort of archiving process, and separate databases are appropriate.

What would be idea would be a [synonym](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) at the database level.  Alas, that doesn't exist.

So, my recommendation is to put together a process.  Every month after you upload the latest month, do the following:

- Drop the existing "current" database
- Create a new "current" database
- Create views or synonyms for all existing tables and views in the most recent loaded data.
- Create synonyms for the stored procedures and functions.

That should be sufficient -- or more than sufficient.

You can create these objects using dynamic SQL that loops through the appropriate objects in the newly loaded database.